# How to you change the font size when using \chapter and \tableofcontent in Latex

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, titles

I am using a document class `book` for my dissertation and I want to change the font size and alignment when I create the table of content.

Below is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    
\listoffigures  
\listoftables

\newpage
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}\vspace{0.5cm}

\end{document}
```

I want to align as per the below picture:

[image: The alignment wanted]

The alignment I am getting based on the code is as follows:

[image: Aligment from the code]

Edit: Thank you, this is helpful. As per the comment I used fncychap package, and it worked but I am facing another issue. The title gets populated in the header, I want only the page number. I read the package and document and did not find any resources to fix it. I tried fancyhdr package but was still not able to get rid of the title in header. Please help.
[image: Header issue]

Comment: You can change the font size in section titles via the `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `fncychap` package, you could have:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{fncychap}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase %  also for "Table of content" etc.
\ChNameVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}
\ChNumVar{\normalsize\mdseries}
\ChTitleVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}

% following is inspired by pages 8-9 of the manual of the fncychap package
% Adding of \vspace{-3cm} to move up the word "CHAPTER" and his number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
\vspace{-3cm}\CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter\par\nobreak 
\vskip 10\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\newpage 

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

%\vspace{0.5cm}

\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

To answer to the edited question (remove the chapter title in the header of pages) and to a comment (customize the sections and subsections in the same style as chapters), you could add this in the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to customize the header
\pagestyle{fancy} % uses the `fancy`style
\fancyhf{} % wipe the default settings
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % page number on the right side
\renewcommand\headrule{} % no line between the head and the body
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % to remove a warning

% to customize \section and \subsection
% Lengths might be adapted
% The number in the second argument of `\@startsection` is the level of the sectionning command (1 of section, 2 for subsection, 3 for subsubsection, ...)
% As we would center the sectionning title, keep the 3rd argument to 0pt
% 4th and 5th argument are vertical rubber length (before and after the sectionning title)
% This layout is not optimal (for exemple, no visual difference between chapter title and subsection title, they uses the same font size)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{12pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}{10pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\normalfont\centering}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}{10pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}{10pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\normalfont\centering}}
\makeatother
```

Results:

[image]

And for the header:

[image]

Comment: +1. Two issues, though. First, since the instructions (I know, the OP's screenshot isn't the clearest) say that the chapter-level header must not be in bold, you may want to replace `\bfseries` with `\mdseries` in the `\ch...` instructions. Second, the code's output currently doesn't match what's shown in the screeenshot. Please fix.

Comment: @Mico I have screenshooted page 4 of the output. What is wrong? The pages 1-3 are Table of content, List of figures and List of tables (as in the OP code).

Comment: @Mico Do you speak about about the line spacing in the OP screenshot?

Comment: In the screenshot the OP posted, one finds the instruction that the chapter and section headers should not be typeset in bold. Since the headers of the ToC, LoF, and LoT are (semantically speaking) unnumbered chapter-level headers, they too should be typeset non-bold and all-uppercase.

Comment: Done. You're right, I added `\ChTitleUpperCase`.

Comment: Thank you @quark67, how do I do the same for the subsection?

Comment: @quark67, Please can you check the edit part in my question? I am very grateful for your response.

Comment: @Roshni Done. But perhaps there are better approach.